# load style-m only in sub domain but and in main domain load style-l

Tags: magento2, theme

I was looking forward to load mobile style like `style-m.less` only to sub domain

Ex in `m.domain.com` Magento 2 will only load `style-m.css` or `style-m.less`, and in `domain.com` Magento will load only `style-l.css` or `style-l.less`.

But I don't know where to start here. Can any one give me a hint or how to do this is very much appreciated?

Comment: I've already got an answer for this question but not exactly as what i wanted. but then it give's me the same ouput as expected. by using two different themes in same style. but the media query is removed. in main theme. I don't know if it is a best practise but it works good for me.